# Pass window.location.href to Shiny app

Tags: r, web-applications, shiny

I would like to be able to pass arguments to my Shiny apps using `window.location.href` type functions.

For example, I would like to be able to use:

```
### http://econometricsbysimulation.shinyapps.io/OLS-App/?nobs=500
```

To tell the app to start the number of observations to simulate at `500`.

Thanks for any help you can provide,

Francis

Comment: use `session$clientData` and `parseQueryString` see https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-testapp/tree/master/clientdata

Answer (score 0):

In your server function you need to pass a `session` argument. `session$clientData` then contains `session$clientData$url_search` which has the relevant information. There is a utility function `parseQueryString` that will allow you to parse the data:

```
library(shiny)
runApp(port = 5678, list(ui = fluidPage(
  headerPanel("Shiny Client Data"),
  column(6, 
    h3("clientData values"),
    verbatimTextOutput("summary"),
    h3("Parsed URL query"),
    verbatimTextOutput("queryText")
  ),
  column(6,
         plotOutput('myPlot'))
)
, server = function(input, output, session){
  output$summary <- renderText({
    cnames <- names(session$clientData)
    allvalues <- lapply(cnames, function(name) {
      item <- session$clientData[[name]]
      if (is.list(item)) {
        list_to_string(item, name)
      } else {
        paste(name, item, sep=" = ")
      }
    })
    paste(allvalues, collapse = "\n")
  })
  output$queryText <- renderText({
    query <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)
    paste(names(query), query, sep = "=", collapse=", ")
  })
  output$myPlot <- renderPlot({
    query <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)
    if('nobs' %in% names(query)){
      plot(runif(as.integer(query$nobs)))
    }else{
      plot(runif(100))
    }
  })
}
))
```

You can run the above code. The app will be viewable on `http://127.0.0.1:5678`. Navigate to `http://127.0.0.1:5678?nobs=15` and you can see the query string in action:

[image]